# How to sample multivariate random normals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose $\Omega=(0,1)$, $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(0,1)$ and $P$ the Lebesgue measure. Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$ denote the standard normal CDF. Then, we can generate $X\sim N(0,1)$ as follows: $X(\omega)=\Phi^{-1}(\omega)$. This works because
$$
P(\omega:X(\omega)\leq c)=P(\omega:\Phi^{-1}(\omega)\leq c)=P(\omega:\omega\leq\Phi(c))=\Phi(c).
$$
**My question**: how do I generalize this to generate $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ $\sim$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$? I would like to do this with a single $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},P)$, possibly redefined from their above meanings.

I'm guessing that $\Omega=(0,1)^n$, $\mathcal{B}$ is some sort of product of the one-dimensional Borel $\sigma$-algebra. But I lack the language to describe this precisely. I think this is a standard exercise so I would really appreciate a rigorous work out so I can learn this properly. A reference recommendation for this type of constructions will also be very helpful.

Comment: You can just take $\mathcal{B}$ to be the product $\sigma$-algebra of $n$ copies of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. This is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all products $A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_n$ where each factor is a Borel subset of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Also, I think your title is a bit misleading, because usually "generating random variables" means sampling from a distribution numerically, and sampling normal variables numerically by inverting the CDF is a bad idea. Instead we use some clever procedure such as the Box-Muller algorithm.

Comment: +1 to lan's comment. Also refer to Luc Devroye's book *Non-uniform Random Variate Generation*.

Comment: @Ian I'll change the title. If you elaborate on your comments, I'll accept them too.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks. I have obtained a copy and will look up the relevant info when time permits.

Comment: I don't think that title is very clear either. What you're trying to do is write down a probability space and a measurable function on that probability space such that the measurable function has the $N(0,I_n)$ distribution. It has little to do with sampling, except to the extent that when you actually *are* sampling, having such a function in hand is useful. One way write down such a probability space is to consider $(0,1)^n$, with the product Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then $X((\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n))=(\Phi^{-1}(\omega_1),\dots,\Phi^{-1}(\omega_n))$.